# Ionic v2 create project issue

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic2

I'm trying to get ionic2 up and running by following the Getting Started page. I ran the npm -g install cordova ionic command in step one and everything seemed fine but when I ran step two ionic start --v2 myApp tabs I received errors.

```
CCasadMBP:Sites ccasad$ ionic start --v2 myAppv2 tabs

/Users/ccasad/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/start_wizard.js:94
      ps.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                                  ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.start_wizard (/Users/ccasad/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/index.js:25:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ccasad/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/start.js:13:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)


/Users/ccasad/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/start_wizard.js:94
      ps.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                                  ^^
Unexpected token => (CLI v2.2.1)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: 1.8.2 
ios-sim version: 5.0.3 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v0.12.6
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2.1 Build version 7C1002
```

I've had things running fine for ionic v1 so not sure why things in npm aren't working for v2. The error almost seems like it doesn't understand ES6 arrow functions or something since it's saying unexpected token on the =>.

Any ideas how to deal with this? Do I need to reinstall node?

Thanks

Comment: So I basically uninstalled and reinstalled node and npm using brew on MacOS. I couldn't find a way to get around this error. Uninstalling and reinstalling the latest version of each did the trick. Oh well, I hope if I have to do anything with my older project things will work, guess I'll cross that bridge if I ever need to. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Best way uninstall and delete node from `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)` and install the latest version.

OR

This is a ionic bug in this file

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\start_wizard.js
```

For compile this syntax of node.js you need to new version of Node.js and so you must be change all lambda syntax from function to normalize codes for older versions:

```
 ps.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    var d = data.toString('utf-8');
    if(d.indexOf('dev server running') >= 0) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      res.end(JSON.stringify({
        'status': 'success'
      }));
    }
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
```

To :

```
  ps.stdout.on('data',function (data)  {
    var d = data.toString('utf-8');
    if(d.indexOf('dev server running') >= 0) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      res.end(JSON.stringify({
        'status': 'success'
      }));
    }
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
```

Full Correct file : [Download](https://gist.github.com/ahmadaghazadeh/d8c4b8ed09e9e31c34fd46998c54f68c)

Comment: I'm on a Mac so not sure if this would work or not. Thanks though. Got it to work by uninstalling and reinstalling via Brew.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this way it could work for you, even i had a issue i have resolved this way . I believe look like node migration issue .Try to set latest version (e.g 6.9.4).Before doing do `clean npm` and then install.Hope this should work